# how to edit woocommerce receipt to include full name

Tags: email, woocommerce, receipt

How do I change woocommerce receipt to include customer's FULL name, not just first name?

I want to CHANGE get_billing_first_name to "get full name", but am not sure of syntax. this is current code from customer-processing-order.php:

```
<?php /* translators: %s: Customer first name */ ?>
<p><?php printf( esc_html__( 'Hi %s,', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $order->get_billing_first_name() ) ); ?></p>
```

thanks

Comment: Use `<p><?php printf( esc_html__( 'Hi %s,', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $order->get_billing_first_name() . ' ' . $order->get_billing_last_name() ) ); ?></p>` to get the full name.